# Domain amazon server windows

Tags: server

Domain amazon server windows
domain:
http://ec2-35-167-45-49.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
Is work in server. But not work in internet.. why?
i run flask server witch ip 0 0 0 0
in windows amazon

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port ='80', debug=True, threaded=True)
```

[Screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOdyL.jpg)

in settings server i add group http

Comment: Its good practice to add a description of the error/problem you are encountering.  If in a language other than English, please try and translate to English.